# Change data in Class when List<sub-class> data is changed

Tags: c#, inner-classes

I have a class STimer that has a List in it.  The serviceDetail is monitored on a timer very often, and rarely changes, but when it does change I want to get the fact that the data changed without looping through the list due to processing power.  Maybe this is a duplicate question that I just don't know how to search for it, but I have been trying.  Here is a code Sample:

```
class STimers
{

public class ServiceDetail
    {
        private int _serviceKey;
        private bool _isRunning = true;
        private bool _runningStateChanged = false;

        public bool isRunning
        {
            get { return _isRunning; }
            set
            {
                //Check to see if the data is the same, if so, don't change, if not, change and flag as changed
                if(_isRunning = value) { return; }
                else
                {
                    _isRunning = value;
                    _runningStateChanged = true;
        <-- Update STimers._dataChanged to true -->
                }
            }
        }

    }


public List<ServiceDetail> _serviceMonitors = new List<ServiceDetail>();
public bool _dataChanged = false;


}
```

I could do a .Find on the list to return all of the _serviceMonitors._runningStateChanged=true, but that seems like a lot of work parsing the List every time the timer fires, when likely only 1 out of 1,000 loops will actually have a change.

Is this even possible, or do I need to move the check for changes out of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get this by adding an **event** to your ServiceDetail class

```
public class ServiceDetail
{
    public event EventHandler<ListChangedEventArgs> ListChanged;
    private int _serviceKey;
    private bool _isRunning = true;
    private bool _runningStateChanged = false;

    private void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e){
        if (ListChanged != null) ListChanged(this, e);
    }       

    public bool isRunning
    {
        get { return _isRunning; }
        set
        {
            //Check to see if the data is the same, if so, don't change, if not, change and flag as changed
            if(_isRunning = value) { return; }
            else
            {
                _isRunning = value;
                _runningStateChanged = true;
                OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(this));
    <-- Update STimers._dataChanged to true -->
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And define your **ListChangedEventArgs** class like this

```
public class ListChangedEventArgs:EventArgs
{
    public ServiceDetail serviceDetail { get; set; }
    public ListChangedEventArgs(ServiceDetail s)
    {
        serviceDetail = s;
    }
}
```

And then register to the event for each servicedetail added to the list

```
s.ListChanged += (sender, args) => YourFunction();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I am marking this as correct, although I did not use it, as I believe it answers the spirit of what I was looking for.  I took the process in a different direction and decided to handle the event of data changing in the loop itself, instead of finishing the loop, looking for changes, then looping through the changes.  Thank you for the suggestion as it prodded me in the direction I decided to take.